# const = 0 после прототипа функции что означает?

Tags: c++, qt

в библиотеке qwt, в файле **[qwt_series_data.h](https://sourceforge.net/p/qwt/code/HEAD/tree/branches/qwt-6.2/src/qwt_series_data.h#l78)**, объявлен класс: `QwtSeriesData`. Что означает `virtual size_t size() const = 0;`, а именно `= 0`?

```
template <typename T>
class QwtSeriesData
{
public:
    //! Constructor
    QwtSeriesData();

    //! Destructor
    virtual ~QwtSeriesData();

    //! \return Number of samples
    virtual size_t size() const = 0;

    /*!
      Return a sample
      \param i Index
      \return Sample at position i
     */
    virtual T sample( size_t i ) const = 0;

    /*!
       Calculate the bounding rect of all samples

       The bounding rect is necessary for autoscaling and can be used
       for a couple of painting optimizations.

       qwtBoundingRect(...) offers slow implementations iterating
       over the samples. For large sets it is recommended to implement
       something faster f.e. by caching the bounding rectangle.

       \return Bounding rectangle
     */
    virtual QRectF boundingRect() const = 0;

    /*!
       Set a the "rect of interest"

       QwtPlotSeriesItem defines the current area of the plot canvas
       as "rectangle of interest" ( QwtPlotSeriesItem::updateScaleDiv() ).
       It can be used to implement different levels of details.

       The default implementation does nothing.

       \param rect Rectangle of interest
    */
    virtual void setRectOfInterest( const QRectF &rect );

protected:
    //! Can be used to cache a calculated bounding rectangle
    mutable QRectF d_boundingRect;

private:
    QwtSeriesData<T> &operator=( const QwtSeriesData<T> & );
};
```

Comment: Чистая виртуальная функция

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что этот класс — *абстрактный базовый*. Вы не можете создавать экземпляры данного класса, а можете использовать его только для наследования и для обращения через указатели и ссылки.

Наследник такого класса, если он должен быть *конкретным* классом и давать возможность создавать объекты, должен переопределить все *чисто виртуальные функции* (те самые, заканчивающиеся на `= 0;`).

Answer (score 0):

в этом случае слово const означает, что этот метод не будет изменять объект к которому он относится. этот метод можно будет вызывать даже для константного объекта, а =0 означает что метод виртуальный. Этот метод не имеет реализации, и необходимо, чтобы в каком-либо дочернем классе он был реализован путем переопределения (override).